# Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'UILabel?'

Tags: xcode

I try to program a calculator. But with the reset button, I keep coming up with this error message: Can not assign value of type 'String' to type `UILabel?`.

I have already tried to replace `label` with `label.text`.

here is some of my code.The error message appears behind `label`

```swift
if sender.tag == 11 {
    label = " "     
    previousNumber = 0;
    numberOnScreen = 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the label?

Comment: The error says that `label` is `UILabel` so `label.text = ""` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `label` is declared as a `Label?`, try:

```
if let realLabel = label {
    realLabel.text = "  "
} else {
    print("There is no label")
}
```